# Cannot read File from fs with FileReader

Tags: node.js, fs

Hi i am trying to read a file and i am having trouble with the fileReader readAsArrayBuffer function in nodejs.

```
var FileReader = require("filereader");

let p12_path = __dirname + "/file.p12";

var p12xxx = fs.readFileSync(p12_path, "utf-8");

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(p12xxx);//The problem is here
reader.onloadend = function() {
  arrayBuffer = reader.result;
  var arrayUint8 = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  var p12B64 = forge.util.binary.base64.encode(arrayUint8);
  var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(p12B64);
  var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);

  ............
}
```

-------The error

```
Error: cannot read as File: "0�6�\.............
```

Comment: Where is the FileReader class from? it is not native JS / NodeJS.

Comment: hello Niklas i imported as var FileReader = require("filereader"); its a npm pack, https://www.npmjs.com/package/filereader

Comment: In addition to my answer: can you describe what kind of file you want to read and what you intend to do with the data?

Comment: Another one: Is in nessecary to use the npm package filereader? Without any more context, it seems to be better to just go with the native `fs.readFile(path, callback)`

Comment: Niklas I am trying to adopt an implementation to sign an xml with xades-bes, This implementation was made to work on the browser side. So I am trying to adapt it to work server side in nodejs. These is a code on codesanbox codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-chaum-px00o?file=/src/xades-bes.js –

Comment: I think I should change the FileReader for some solution in fs, but I am really new to the topic

Comment: Without knowing the hole context I cannot help you any further. The only thing I want to tell you, is that there is often no way to migrate/translate client-side JS that uses advanced features of browsers' WebAPIs to server-side NodeJS (and the other way around) than just replan and recode the hole thing. Sry...

Comment: thanx. Anyway, in codesanbox I put the code and you can take a look at it. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-chaum-px00o?file=/src/xades-bes.js

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a PDF file which is not a text based format and should not have an encoding specified. As per the fs docs "If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string" but because its mostly a binary file its reading invalid UTF8 characters. When you exclude the encoding it should give you a Buffer object instead which is what you most likely want.

Comment: when i remove the utf-8 encoding it gives me this error: Error: cannot read as File: {"type": "Buffer", "data": [48,130.5 .....

Comment: What is filereader supposed to be doing for you here and why are you trying to use it on a file you have already read?

Comment: I am trying to adopt an implementation to sign an xml with xades-bes, This implementation was made to work on the browser side. So I am trying to adapt it to work server side in nodejs. These is a code on codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-chaum-px00o?file=/src/xades-bes.js

Comment: You dont need filereader on the server. Just drop it in favor of fs to save on node modules size.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [npm filereader Doc](https://github.com/node-file-api/FileReader), the reader created with `fs.readFileSync(p12_path, "utf-8");` needs to  get a path of a file in the `utf-8` encoding, otherwise it cannot read it.

The printed out `"0�6�\.............` shows the file is obviously not in utf8 and therefor not readable.

Comment: i test let p12_path = __dirname + "/file.p12" and have read the relative path ok

Comment: the way the path is given is ok, but not the file / the content. It is not a uft8-text file.